# Access and Write data securely between server and client on a public-use application

Tags: python, security, server, client, pysftp

I'm working on coding an application in Python 3 for users to send and retrieve data between others with this application. The process would be a client inputting an encoded string, and using a server as a middle man to then send data to another client. I'm well versed in what would be used for the client application, but this server knowledge I am new to. I have a VPS server up and running, and I researched and found the module `pysftp` would be good for transferring data back and forth. However, I'm concerned about the security of the server when using the application. This module requires the authentication details of the server when making a connection, and I don't think having my server's host, username and password in the application code is very safe. What would be the safe way to go about this?
Thanks,
Gunner

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use pre-generated authentication keys. If you are familiar with the process of using the `ssh-keygen` tool to create SSH key pairs, it's the same thing. You just generate the key pair, place the private key on the client machine, and put the public key on the target server. Then you can use `pysftp` like this:

```
with pysftp.Connection('hostname', username='me', private_key='/path/to/keyfile') as sftp:
   <do some stuff>
```

the authentication is handled using the key pair and no password is required. This isn't to say that your security issue is solved: the private key is still a sensitive credential that needs to be treated like a password. The advantage is that you don't have a plaintext password stored in a file anywhere, and you are using a well established and secure process to manage authentication. The private key is set with permission `0600` to prevent anyone but the owner from accessing it.